# How can I get array data from Axios to convert it to string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to show some data in my React component, but there's some data I cannot get.

I can get any other simple data, but I'm having problems to get the data inside an array.

The API format is the following:

```
res.data
   genres: (3) [(...), (...), (...)]
      0: {name: 'Adventure'}
      1: {name: 'Fantasy'}
      1: {name: 'Sci-Fi'}
```

And this is my code:

```
const [anime, setAnime] = useState([])
  const [random, setRandom] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://api.jikan.moe/v3/anime/${random}`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
        setAnime(res.data)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        randomAnime()
      })
    
  }, [random])

const randomAnime = () => {
   setRandom(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100))
}

return (
   <Anime title={anime.title} genres={anime.genres} />
)
}
```

Then, I pass anime.genres as props to another component. There, I try to render the following:

```
genres.map((genre) =>   
   <span key={genre.name.toString()}>
      {genre.name}
   </span>
)
```

And this error shows:

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')**

In reality, what I want to render is the following string (this part is not implemented yet, i want to merge all array items in one string separated by commas): Adventure, Fantasy, Sci-Fi.

Hope someone can help me, I've been struck all noon. Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: looks like `genre` may be coming up empty/undefined. You may want to put exception handling around that.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent this by checking if genres is not undefined before trying to map it.

Something like this:

```
{
 genres !== undefined &&
 genres.map((genre) =>   
    <span key={genre.name.toString()}>
       {genre.name}
    </span>
 )
}
```

If you want to show the items in the array with a , and display them as a string, you could use the [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent this by adding default data for gener in props.
Also if "gener.name" already a string, don't need to use .toString() for key, just put gener.name is enough
If you need new array only with string items, just create him like a:
const newArray = genres.map(g=> g.name)